# -UseDefaultCredential vs. -Credential in PowerShell (401 Error)

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am writing a script in PowerShell that is testing login credentials to a target SharePoint 2013 URL that are passed through to an Invoke-WebRequest command that calls the URL in question.  When I use -UseDefaultCredential, the returned status is a 200, but when I replace that and try the following code passed in to a -Credential property of the same command, I get a 401 error:

```
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $userPassword = "password"
[SecureString] $userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
[PSCredential] $userCredential = New-Object -TypeName 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("userName", $userPassword)
Invoke-Webrequest -Credential $userCredential -uri "https://connect.adler.edu" 
powershell -noexit
```

Any thoughts as to why I'm getting the 401 Error when using the -Credential property?  Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760070/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized) help?

Comment: Thanks, Neko, but still getting a 401 after amending my code after following your link...

Comment: Have you tried `domain\username` format? In the script.you only use `username`

Comment: robdy -- thanks for your input... yes, I've tried the domain]username arrangement, too...still Error 401