# How to protect ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to implement **ASP.NET Web API 2** i.e.

```
[RoutePrefix("orders")] 
public class OrdersController : ApiController 
{ 
    [Route("{id}")] 
    public Order Get(int id) { } 
    [Route("{id}/approve")] 
    public Order Approve(int id) { } 
}
```

I am wondering how it can be protected?

Can we use **ASP.NET Identity** for that, for instance?

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the class and then send the basic authentication information via the header.

Comment: Sounds good! Could you provide any sample how to `send the basic authentication information via the header`. Also... Should it be ASP .NET identity database?

Comment: @ClarkKent, here is an [example on how to build the header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764577/forcing-basic-authentication-in-webrequest). And yeah, the basic ASP.NET user database.

Comment: There is a a complete example with source code on using basic authentication with ASP.NET Identity in the SimpleSecurity project https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.Filters/BasicAuthorizeAttribute.cs . Look at the reference application for an example.

Comment: @KevinJunghans Thank you! Put it like an aswer pls. At least I will +1 coz it has `How to add basic authentication to Web API's.   `https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom AuthorizeAttribute using ASP.NET Identity that handles basic authentication for your Web API's. There is a a complete example with source code on using basic authentication with ASP.NET Identity in the [SimpleSecurity Project](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/).  You can find the [source code for the  custom AuthorizeAttribute here](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.Filters/BasicAuthorizeAttribute.cs).  Look at the reference application for an example on how to use it. The [source code for the client side code is here](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.RefApp/Views/TestBasicAuth/Index.cshtml).  There is a [discussion on implementing basic authentication in Web API's here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html).  Although this article references SimpleMembership the same principals were applied to the implementation using ASP.NET Identity.